# При клике на слайд неправильно берутся данные из data-атрибута

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Есть слайдер с бесконечной прокруткой, при клике на слайд открывается модалка, в которой открывается нужное видео. В каждом слайде в data-атрибуде прописаны ссылки на видео. Проблема в том, что на первом кругу слайдов все открывается верно, но когда мы начинаем пролистывать дальше, то при пролистывании вправо перестает работать ссылка на первый слайд, а при пролистывании влево - на последний слайд. В чем может быть причина? Предполагаю, что проблема может быть связана с созданием дубликатов слайдов при зацикленной прокрутке.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var videoSrc = '';
  $('.video_link').click(function(){
    videoSrc = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+$(this).attr('data-src');
    $('.videoModal_video').attr('src', videoSrc);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var videoSrc = '';
  $( /* добавить селектор в котором находится слайдер */ ).on('click', '.video_link', function() {
    videoSrc = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).data('src');
    $('.videoModal_video').attr('src', videoSrc);
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло